# Windows 7 wakes from sleep mode without exterior notice

Tags: windows-7, sleep

I close the lid of my laptop which puts it to sleep mode. However, it seems to wake up for a few seconds at full hours (10am and 13pm). I notice it, because it plays a youtube video audibly for these few seconds each.

What causes this behaviour, and can/should I suppress it?

Comment: Open Windows’ Event Viewer, navigate to the “System” log and look for power events. There should be one for every wakeup that states the cause of the wakeup.

Comment: McAfee Service Controller. Thank you for your service, McAfee. How can I turn that off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been having the same problem. I believe it is being caused by the recient "Get Windows 10" app that installed as a windows update. Just uninstall the update to get rid of this app.

Open CONTROL PANNEL / PROGRAMS AND FEATURES / select SHOW INSTALLED UPDATES, and find KB3035583. Right click this update and select uninstall.